# Refresh the content in div using jquery/ajax in ruby on rails not working

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax

I used ajax to make a post request. After I get the respond in html, `@edit_mobile_form.errors.present?` was true but nothing happened, error text wasn't showed.

Then I tried to reload my div using one of the following code. None of them worked.

```
$('.bar').html($(data).find(".bar").html())
$('.bar').append($(data).find(".bar").html())
$("#foo").load(" #foo");
$("#foo").load(" #foo > *");
$('#foo').load(document.URL +  ' #foo');
```

script

```
$.ajax({
            url: "/my-url",
            type: "POST",
            data: {
                some-data: ""
            },
            dataType: "html",
            success: function (data, status) {
                console.log(data);
                // I refresh div here
            },
            error: function (xhr, status, error) {
                console.log(error.stack);
            }
        });
```

index.html.erb

```
<% if @edit_mobile_form.errors.present? %>
            <div id="foo" class="bar">
            <dl style="margin-top: 8px">
              <dd>
                <ul>
                  <% @edit_mobile_form.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
                    <li><%= msg if msg.is_a?(String) && !msg.empty? %></li>
                  <% end %>
                </ul>
              </dd>
            </dl>
            </div>
          <% end %>
```

Comment: HI, what does `console.log(data);` shows ?

Comment: @Swati the whole html page

Comment: starting from here `<div id="foo" class="bar">..` ?

Comment: @Swati no, i mean the full page. Including <head> and <body>

Comment: do `console.log($(data).find(".bar").html())` see if that showing you correct values or not

Comment: @Swati yes, I've got what I want to show when logging

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/231189/discussion-between-hai-hack-and-swati).